# Without using a plugin, how do I exclude multiple categories by name?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have (2) categories I want to exclude from the blog, how do I do this without a WP Plugin and by name not ID?

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=5'.'&paged='.$paged); $exclude = get_cat_ID('feature');
$q = 'cat=-'.$exclude;
query_posts($q);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are using a couple of different methods (WP_Query & query_posts) in your code for retrieving posts. Is that intended? In case you aren't sure which one to use, take a look at [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755) diagram. This is one of my favorite Wordpress diagrams. You can achieve what you are trying to achieve using either WP_Query() or query_posts(). Let me know if you need further assistance once you have chosen which method to use.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be saving that. I cleaned it up to allow pagination. <?php
  $temp = $wp_query;
  $wp_query= null;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query();
  $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=5'.'&paged='.$paged); 
  $exclude = get_cat_ID('feature');
  $q = 'cat=-'.$exclude;
  query_posts( array( 'cat' => $q,'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) );
  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  ?>        How can I use just one? I'm not a PHP expert. Though Pagination works here, I'm still only able to exclude 1 category from appearing in the blog.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$category_ids_to_ignore = array(3,4);  // replace 3 & 4 with the actual catgory ids you want to exclude
$posts = new WP_Query(array('category__not_in' => $category_to_ignore, 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged')));

while($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post();
endwhile;
```